# Assign user based on account zip code

Tags: trigger, custom-object, account

I'm looking for a way to do the following. 
I need to automatically assign users to accounts based on the account's zip code. 
The idea is that these users will be responsible for a number of accounts and the criteria behind this is the "Post Code" in the account page layout.

I'm thinking on a few options but I was wondering if anyone have experiences on doing this or something similar to this.

The user to be assign will be inserted on a lookup-relationship field (Sales_Responsible__c) in the account.

I was thinking on creating an object to put all the zip codes and then assign the codes to the correct user. 
After this I was thinking on using a trigger to update the Sales_Responsible__c based on the account zip code on insert and update.
Is this something logical?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Viasur

Your approach makes good sense. Some things to think about:

1. Handling postal codes that are invalid (no rep found in your mapping object)
2. When an Account's postal code changes, do you automatically assign a new sales rep?
3. Be sure to bulkify the trigger as a batch load of many Accounts should only do one SOQL to fetch all sales reps for all postal codes in the trigger set
4. Make the trigger efficient and not query on update for postal codes that haven't changed (the normal use case)
5. Non US postal codes need normalization as they may or may not have spaces
6. Handling nine digit US postal codes